# Sperate the list based on a value in python

Tags: python, list, split

I have a list like below:-

```
list1 = ['box','ball','new','bat','chess','old']
```

I want to split this list based on values. In the above list, I want to insert the values before `'new'` into a new list and the values before `'old'` have to be inserted into a new list. The values before `'new'` and `'old'` can be one or more but here it has two values. I tried using `split_after` but I am getting the below result:-

```
from more_itertools import split_after

list1 = ['box','ball','new','bat','chess','old']
list(split_after(list1, lambda x: x == "new"))
```

Result:-

```
[['box', 'ball', 'new'], ['bat', 'chess', 'old']]
```

But desire output:-

```
result1 = ['box', 'ball']
result2 = ['bat', 'chess']
```

Comment: Just remove the last item from each list?

Comment: Yeah you already solved the issue, just pop the last value of each list.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might use [split_at](https://more-itertools.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#more_itertools.split_at), and in the lambda check for either `new` or `old`.

Then remove the empty lists from the result.

```
from more_itertools import split_at

list1 = ['box', 'ball', 'new', 'bat', 'chess', 'old']
print(list(filter(None, split_at(list1, lambda x: x == "new" or x == "old"))))
```

Output

```
[['box', 'ball'], ['bat', 'chess']]
```

Answer (score 2):

Another solution, using standard `itertools.groupby`:

```py
list1 = ["box", "ball", "new", "bat", "chess", "old"]

from itertools import groupby

out = [
    list(g) for v, g in groupby(list1, lambda k: k in {"new", "old"}) if not v
]
print(out)
```

Prints:

```py
[['box', 'ball'], ['bat', 'chess']]
```

Answer (score 1):

If the values are more based on which you have to split like **new** and **old**, you can do this:

```
list1 = ['box','ball','new','bat','chess','old']
split_val = ['new','old'] # Based on these values you can separate list. You can add more values here.

new_list=[]
k=0
for i in split_val:
    for j in range(len(list1)):
        if list1[j]==i and j!=0:
            new_list.append(list1[k:j])
            k=j+1

new_list.append(list1[k:])
new_list = [i for i in new_list if len(i)>0]
print(new_list)
```

Output:

```
[['box', 'ball'], ['bat', 'chess']]
```